# make: *** No rule to make target `tools', needed by `all'. Stop

Tags: makefile, embedded-linux

I was trying to install the Flite1.4. The installation is two steps

1. `./configure`
2. `make`

But `make` gives me this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `tools', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

Please help to resolve this error.

```
[angus@bu flite-1.4-release]$ ls
ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS  config.status  Exports.def      Makefile       src
bin               config.sub     fliteDll.vcproj  missing        testsuite
build             configure      flite.sln        mkinstalldirs  wince
config            configure.in   include          palm
config.guess      COPYING        install-sh       README
config.log        doc            lang             sapi

[angus@cebu flite-1.4-release]$ ./configure

checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for ar... ar
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for mmap... yes
checking sys/soundcard.h usability... yes
checking sys/soundcard.h presence... yes
checking for sys/soundcard.h... yes
checking machine/soundcard.h usability... no
checking machine/soundcard.h presence... no
checking for machine/soundcard.h... no
checking sys/audioio.h usability... no
checking sys/audioio.h presence... no
checking for sys/audioio.h... no
checking mmsystem.h usability... no
checking mmsystem.h presence... no
checking for mmsystem.h... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config/config
config.status: creating config/system.mak


[angus@bu flite-1.4-release]$ make

make: *** No rule to make target `tools', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Makefile` looks bad. Somewhere in it there is a like looking like:

```
all: <some-other-targets> tools
```

Which says that the target `all` requires the target `tools` to be made. But there is no line
in the Makefile defining the target `tools`.

That seems strange for a released code. Some idea on how to go on:

1. Make sure the target `tools` is correctly spelled. Case matters.
2. You may try to remove the dependency of `all` on `tools` by removing tools on the line described above and rerun `make`. This does not build you package completly, but at least you know if there are some other issues to resolve.
3. Run `configure --help` and look at the available options like `--enable-XXXXX` to may be used with `configure`. Using options with `configure` may modify the `Makefile` and avoid building the `tools` target.

Note that each time `configure` is called, the `Makefile` is being regenerated: so your modification may go lost.